# overlay transparent layer in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm working with an icon set where some icons have "holes" that are created by setting a white object over a dark one.
For my purposes, I want these areas to be actually transparent, so I think I need to cut out the inner shape from the outer shape.

As an example:
The white circle in the image below looks like a transparent area since it has the color of the background. It's actually just filled white.
If I were to make it transparent, you'd just see black.
What's the way to make this area transparent without changing the structure?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select both the black shape, and the white shape.
2. Do *Path > Difference*
3. If you want to see the transparency/checkerboard do *File > Document Properties*, and  select the "Checkerboard Background" option.  The object is still transparent whether you switch on the Checkerboard or not.

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the command combine from the path menu as shown:
[image]create the two shapes;

[image] Put the circle behind the square; [image] select both the shapes [image] use combine from the path menu